# accessing D3 dynamical json object in Rails view

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js, coffeescript

I am learning D3 and to start, I try to display a graph where I hard-code the json data

I have created a JSFiddle to illustrate this http://jsfiddle.net/Nu95q/1/

wich displays the graph correctly

But now I would like to integrate this in my Rails project passing the json data with an ajax link so upon clicking the link the json data is created in the controller and the graph is replaced with the new one.

The D3 code is in `assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee`

And this is what I have in my controller:

```
  def identification_item
    @sii = params[:sii_id]
    @fragments = SpectrumIdentificationItem.find(@sii).fragments
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js { render json: @fragments }
   end
 end
```

I can see by checking chrome's inspector Network panel, that a json object is generated with the correct data,

Now my question is How can I access this json variable in D3? I have tried to substitute the hardcoded variable with my json generated in the controller like this:

```
jsonFragmentIons = @fragments
```

But it seems @fragments is not accessible in `assets/javascripts/my_controller.js.coffee`

(I have checked SO for "accessing json in D3" but all questions I have checked so far seem to refer either to reading a .json  file or a static variable containing the json and not a dynamical json object)

Additionally I might be lacking some basic concepts on how json data is passed between the client and server sides, I am pretty new to it. So any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is facing the same issue, I'll explain here how I solved this.
Well, it seemed you DO have to use `d3.json`. According to d3 [reference](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Requests) d3.json can be used for "loading data asynchronously" and in that case "code that depends on the loaded data should generally exist within the callback function".
So in my coffeescript  I wrote :

```
d3.json "json_generator_controller/action", (error, json) ->
 return console.warn(error)  if error
 data = json
 visualizeD3spectrum data
```

And then

```
 visualizeD3spectrum = (data) ->
 //D3 svg stuff
```